# How to get multiple VLOOKUP results in one cell?

Tags: lookup, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to search data to get multiple VLOOKUP results in one cell (comma separated). For example I have one spreadsheet:

```
product_id | product_name
--------------------------
123        | product A
456        | product B
789        | product C
```

and a second:

```
product_image   |
--------------------------
123_first.jpg   |
123_second.jpg  |
123_third.jpg   |
456_first.jpg   |
456_sec ........
```

and I'm trying to achieve:

```
product_id | product_name | product_images
--------------------------------------------
123        | product A    | 123_first.jpg, 123_second.jpg, 123_third.jpg
456        | product B    | 456_first.jpg, 456_second.jpg, 456_third.jpg
789        | product C    | 789_first.jpg, 789_second.jpg, 789_third.jpg
```

Comment: Are you familiar with macros?